# CGLIB, Spring and injection by constructor

Tags: spring, cglib

I want to use cglib as my proxy mechanism for spring. problem is, i have some beans who have their dependecies injected by constructor and i cannot change this. CGLIB doesn't seem to like that very much and won't let me instantiate that bean. is there any way around it? (for instance, can i disable cglib proxying for some beans? or better yet, can i have CGLIB proxy those beans also?)

Tx in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A short answer is that you can't proxy such beans. See [SPR-3150](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3150) jira issue.

Comment: obviously, we can look forward to this in cglib 4.0

Comment: according to a [comment by Juergen Hoeller in SPR-3150](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-3150?focusedCommentId=96487&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-96487), with Spring 4.0 this is not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Since Eugene is probably right with his short answer, another way to do it is to use the [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) or [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern, using composition instead of inheritance. Proxy your decorator, and let it have the original bean as dependency.

Or do the sensible thing and switch to interface-based proxies.

Comment: How exactly? I should create a new wrapper class to each one of my classes that use constructor injection? @Sean Patrick Floyd

Comment: yes, basically. or go for interface-based proxies, that's much less pain

Comment: In my it's actually a pain also..I have a service that is written in that specific way ( constructor injection ), and I want to use the capabilities of proxying without doing such a massive change in my code. I cannot move to interface-based proxies also.. I am trying to create my own BeanPostProcessor that will proxy the bean with the constructor arguments, but it's kind of complicated and I am looking for a simpler solution..:-| @Sean Patrick Floyd